# recreating whole SQL Server Database with relations

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

i have used SQL server 2012 and made a huge database with many relations. today i realized using "NCHAR" instead on "NVARCHAR" adds space on end of strings which i don't like it. is there any way to recreate database with relations. I've tried "drop and create" for tables but needs to remove all relations and define them again which is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to alter only the affected tables? like this:

```
SELECT 'alter table '+s.name+'.'+t.name+
' alter column '+c.name+' nvarchar('+convert(varchar(11),c.max_length/2)+') go'
FROM    sys.tables as T
inner join sys.schemas as s
on T.[schema_id]=s.[schema_id]
inner join sys.columns as C
on T.[object_id]=C.[object_id]
and c.system_type_id=239--nchar type
```

, and before that don't forget to use the same kind of mechanism to generate an update statement to remove extra spaces.

Comment: thanks but i didn't get how it works and i should replace which words?(t.name to name of table and c.name to Column's name what else?)+there is no record in database so removing spaces isn't neccessary

Comment: If you run the script it will generate an alter script for every column that have nchar datatype. The results script should be run. If you have no data forget about update